# Wordpress add class after post_class

Tags: wordpress

I try to add a class in the tag article but the function of WordPress prevents me from adding php.

```
<?php post_class() ?>
```

I tried many things like :

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); if (! is_sticky()) { echo "non-sticky";} ?> >
```

But the class is not added ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add it as a parameter to the function:

```
<?php $sticky = !is_sticky() ? "non-sticky" : null; ?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( $sticky ); ?>>
```

Read more about the parameters of this function [in the docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class#Parameters).

Comment: I tried something like this, but I had not succeeded. Thank you !